# Jquery Accordion menu Plugin error

Tags: wordpress

I am getting this error when I load my site after adding the Jquery Accordion plugin from http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/ `jQuery("#dc_jqaccordion_widget-5-item .menu").dcAccordion is not a function` .

I am using WordPress 3.1.4 and this is my first venture in WordPress and I am not sure why am I getting this error. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper head and footer tags in your theme.

Place this code just before the  tag in your head

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

And place this code just before the  tag in your footer

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

It's a jQUery conflict problem.

**Solution:**

By trial and error disabled all your plugins, one by one, and check the conflict with any other plugins. Hope this helps.